# Which chemical compound gives Heineken its sweet taste?

Tags: taste, specialty-beers, nutrition

I don't know about everyone else, but I perceive Heineken as sweet (not quite Pepsi, but still)

[image]

I looked up its nutritional info, and it appears that Heineken has 0 sugars. There exist chemical compounds that are not sugars, but still taste sweet though.

Which chemical compound gives Heineken its sweet taste?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are that the sweet taste comes from the [malt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malt) used in Heineken (and other beers).

Malt contains starches that are easily broken down into simple forms of sugar (like [Maltose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maltose)) early on. [Amylase enzymes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amylase) present in your saliva start breaking down starch into sugars, leading to a sweet taste when drinking Heineken.